# How to get a QGIS Atlas with a fixed scale and dpi of different image forms?

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-atlas

An Atlas with a fixed scale and fixed DPI is required and that the images are clearly within the pages of the given atlas

[image]

using the value for the width and height of the image to set the parameters

bounds_width(@atlas_geometry),
bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)

and in this case - the shape of the layout changes according to the atlas, but the image does not fall clearly within the limits.

[image]

In order for the image to clearly match the atlas, you need to change the scale or dpi. I repeat: it is necessary that the scale and dpi are unchanged, and the width and height of the image change, but within the exact limits of the atlas
How to get a qgis Atlas with a fixed scale and dpi of different image forms

An Atlas with a fixed scale and fixed DPI is required and that the images are clearly within the pages of the given atlas

using the value for the width and height of the image to set the parameters
bounds_width(@atlas_geometry)
bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)
and in this case - the shape of the layout changes according to the atlas, but the image does not fall clearly within the limits. In order for the image to clearly match the atlas, you need to change the scale or dpi. I repeat: it is necessary that the scale and dpi are unchanged, and the width and height of the image change, but within the exact limits of the atlas

[image]

For some reason the generated atlas does not take into account the specified scale and does not increase/decrease the size of the images

sorry for my english (google translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rudzik I guess you need to change the way you create your Atlas pages.

1. Set the page properties `width` and `height` with units in `mm` (normally 1 unit in map canvas equals 1 m, which equals a scale of 1:1000 in layout where 1 unit = 1 mm). To set the properties you have to right click your layout page and select `Page Properties...`. Use the following expressions to export your pages with scale **1:5000**:

```
   Width:  bounds_width( @atlas_geometry ) / 5
   Height: bounds_height( @atlas_geometry ) / 5
```

2. Set `width` and `height` of your Map item:

```
   Width:  @layout_pagewidth
   Height: @layout_pageheight
```

3. Select your Image footprint layer as Atlas coverage layer and enable "Controlled by Atlas" in the properties settings of your Map item (Margin around feature: **0%**)
4. Export Atlas as image or PDF: You can change the **DPI** settings as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped to solve my problem