# How to save an image from a project without a background in QGIS 3.32 (without Print Layout)?

Tags: qgis

How to save the project as an image without a background without going to the Print Layout. In the program settings, I did not find how to change the background to transparent or ignore the background during export.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible with Image Export. But why not using a print layout where you can disable map backgrounds and set the page color opacity to 0 (right click on page => page properties...)?

Comment: By setting the scale and DPI, I get the corresponding image (width, height)
Because of the print layout, I can't do this if I use Atlas https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/467164/142742

Comment: I see no reason why you can't do this using an Atlas (see my anser: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467164/how-to-get-a-qgis-atlas-with-a-fixed-scale-and-dpi-of-different-image-forms)

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be nice to add the "Ignore background" option when exporting